# Using the Matlab-Java-API gives "no nativemvm in java.library.path"

Tags: java, matlab

I am trying to run a Matlab function (Matlab 2017a) from Java (as shown [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)) and want to use the Java Matlab engine API for this purpose. I started adding the engine.jar file to the external libraries (I'm using the IntelliJ IDE). However, this gives the following error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativemvm in java.library.path"

A first search got me [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/320234-using-java-api-gives-no-nativemvm-in-java-library-path) where it says that the matlabroot should be added to the PATH permanently. So I checked my PATH using the Windows UI to find that **matlabroot\R2017a\bin** is already included. However, in my case I still get the error and have no idea what to do now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: Adding \R2017a\bin\ to the PATH is not sufficient. It has to be \R2017a\bin\win64 and then it works.