# how to interface java and matlab

Tags: java, matlab, interface

I would like to execute a Matlab function calling it from Java. I imported the com.mathworks.engine library, but it gives me the following error: no nativemvm in java.library.path . Thanks in advance.

Comment: On internet I read about some path and an environment variable i should set. is it possible? and how can i do? I use a Mac and Netbeans. Thanks

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677816/using-the-matlab-java-api-gives-no-nativemvm-in-java-library-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Add the matlab library to your IDE(eclipse or others) or System (if you don't use any IDEs ), see below:

[image: "system path"]

[Image reference](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/320234-using-java-api-gives-no-nativemvm-in-java-library-path)

Comment: thanks, i read it, but I cannot understand... how can I? very very kind thanks

Comment: @L.Cinelli [steps](https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842) to set environment variable in different os , just append above paths in PATH env variable

Comment: and what do I do with the Variable?